# Conflict between deleted aws IP with the new GC IP

Tags: ip, ssl-certificate

I deleted my aws account and started Google Cloud from scratch. But when I enter my previous IP from aws in address bar it automatically goes to my new website on google. Why is that? I already removed my hosted zones and changed the DNS settings before deletion.

Because of that I'm getting an error on my SSL certificate. SSL checkers still show my self-signed certificate while I created a new one with Comodo. Does anyone knows why is that?

Thank you!
Hiva